# Regarding Final Rethrow

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, ioexception

I read in the documentation of `Precise Rethrow` that, http://www.theserverside.com/tutorial/OCPJP-Use-more-precise-rethrow-in-exceptions-Objective-Java-7

> Basically, you can list specific exceptions in the throws clause of your method, even if they are not explicitly handled by a catch block if:
>
> The try block actually throws that specific exception at some point in time.
>
> The specific Exception isn't already handled at any point by a preceding catch block
>
> The exception named in the throws clause of the method signature must be on the class hierarchy of at least one exception being handled  and rethrown by a catch block (subtype or supertype)

#### Have a look at the code (attention on throws clause of `main`)

```
class OpenException extends Exception {}

class CloseException extends Exception {}

public class PRethrow
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws OpenException, CloseException, java.io.IOException
    {
        boolean flag = true;
        try
        {
            if (flag)
            {
                throw new OpenException();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new CloseException();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
    } 
}
```

It is clearly mentioned in the first condition that, `you can list a specific exception in throws clause if the try block actually throws that specific exception at some point in time.`

In my code the try block never throws `java.io.IOException`, but still including it in throws clause produce no error.

### why?

Comment: You're not throwing an IOException, that's why it's not being thrown. You need throw new IOException(); somewhere.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis : http://www.theserverside.com/tutorial/OCPJP-Use-more-precise-rethrow-in-exceptions-Objective-Java-7

Comment: @PerryMonschau : That's what I am saying, I am not throwing an IOException, so as per the first condition as mentioned in the question, there should be error

Comment: Your code will either throw an OpenException if the flag is true, or a CloseException if the flag is false. What is the problem with this fact? Are you suggesting "throw e;" does not seem to be doing anything?

Answer (score 4):

The quote you mention is misleading:

- If a checked exception may be thrown in your method body you must declare it in the throws clause of the method.
- But you may add *any exception* to the `throws` clause of a method, whether it can actually be thrown or not.

For example this compiles:

```
public void m() throws IOException {}
```

Comment: what does `The try block actually throws that specific exception at some point in time.` this means

Comment: I don't know but it doesn't sound correct. The article is misleading and is about Java 6 which has been EOL for years now - unless you are working on a migration from Java 6 to Java 7 I would not spend too much time on that text...

Answer (score 2):

I think you misunderstood the context in which the article is stating this condition. The article is saying that in Java 7, *not* declaring `Exception` in the `throws` clause is *OK if the `throws` clause declares an exception that is actually thrown by the `try` block*, namely `OpenException` and `CloseException`. In a sense, the compiler of Java 7 is now smart enough to know that only `OpenException` and `CloseException` can be thrown by the `try` block. So it no longer requires that the method declares `throws Exception`.

This has nothing to do with `IOException` and it doesn't change the fact that you can declare any exception to be thrown regardless of whether the exception can actually be thrown or not. The `throws` clause is just part of the method API.

The whole point of the condition stated in the article is that the following:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws OpenException, CloseException, 
                                              java.io.IOException
{
    boolean flag = true;
    try
    {
        if (flag)
        {
            throw new OpenException();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new CloseException();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        throw e;       // this causes a compilation error before Java 7
    }
}
```

compiles in Java 7 but not in Java 6.

Comment: `not declaring Exception in the throws clause is OK if the throws clause declares an exception`, please explain.